# passing value from html to js file

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with passing value to my js file.
I tried do this according to http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html and other posts but it doesn't work.

My html file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var user = 'example_of_user_name';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/file.js}"></script>
```

and in my file.js I would like to do something like that

```
   content[0] = '<div class="thumbnail">\
            <form style="display:inline" method="POST" action="/..." class="from-horizontal">\
            <input type="hidden" id="player" value=user name="player" />\
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>\
             </form>\
               </div>'
```

but this value in my input is always null. When I assign value statically in my input everything works fine.

```
     <input type="hidden" id="player" value='example_of_user_name' name="player" />\
```

**EDIT:**

My namespaces

```
    <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring3-3.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
```

After comments I tried also

```
      content[0] = '<div class="thumbnail">\
    <form style="display:inline" method="POST" action="/..." class="from-horizontal">\
    <input type="hidden" id="player" value=' + user + ' name="player" />\
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>\
     </form>\
     </div>';
```

or

```
    document.getElementById('player').value = user;
```

but it doesn't work. I still get nullpointer.

Comment: `th:src="@{/js/file.js}"` not a valid html syntax.

Comment: why not ? I forgot to mention that I also use thymeleaf

Comment: You've given _src_ the _namespace_ of `th`, but haven't shown us anything suggesting that you have a `th` _namespace_ defined. You also include in the attribute _@{...}_ which again is _unexpected_ for a _HTML interpreter_, it was expecting a _URI_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var user = 'example_of_user_name';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/file.js"></script>
```

Your js file

```
var content = new Array();

content[0] = '<div class="thumbnail">\
        <form style="display:inline" method="POST" action="/..." class="from-horizontal">\
        <input type="hidden" id="player" value=' + user + ' name="player" />\
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Submit</button>\
         </form>\
           </div>';
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/ae53z/)

Comment: Using a literal `[]` instead of `new Array` is faster, shorter and consumes less memory

Answer (score 0):

Could you assign the value to the form element using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('player').value = user;
```